# Show $\lim_{z\to2i} \frac{1}{z-i}=-i$ by the definition of the limit.

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, proof-verification

What should I do now ?

$\left | \frac{1}{z-i}+i \right |=\left | \frac{2+iz}{z-i} \right | < \varepsilon$

$0<|z-2i|<\delta$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that we can write

$$\left|\frac{iz+2}{z-i}\right|=\left|\frac{z-i2}{z-i}\right|$$

Now, if $|z-i2|<1/2$, then, $|z-i|>1/2$.

Hence, we have

$$\begin{align}
\left|\frac{1}{z-i}-(-i)\right|&=\left|\frac{iz+2}{z-i}\right|\\\\
&=\left|\frac{z-i2}{z-i}\right|\\\\
&\le 2|z-i2|\\\\
&<\epsilon
\end{align}$$

whenever $\displaystyle |z-i2|<\delta=\min\left(\frac12,\frac{\epsilon}{2}\right)$

Comment: Many thanks !!! I was wonder if i can reach something with $\left | \frac{2+iz}{z-i} \right |=\left | \frac{2+iz}{z-i+(i-i)} \right |=\left | \frac{2+iz}{z-2i}+\frac{2+iz}{i} \right |=\left | \frac{2+iz}{z-2i}-(2i-z) \right |< \varepsilon$. What do you think about ? Or am I just complicated it ?

Comment: @Ewin Well, $\left|\frac{2+iz}{z-i}\right|\ne \left|\frac{2+iz}{z-2i}+\frac{2+iz}{i}\right|$.  So, that approach isn't valid.

Comment: It's true !! What a mistake. I remeber now why isn't valid. Ok

Comment: Please let me know if there are any other questions.   -Mark

Comment: Would the down voter care to comment?